# Conditional Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I am interested in a method of how to compute the expected number of steps for absorpion in a Markov Chain with only one absorption node and given the starting and pre-final node (before absorption).

So, if the transition probability matrix is given, for example by:

$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/5 & 2/5 & 1/5 & 1/5\\
1/5 & 0 & 1/5 & 1/5 & 2/5\\
2/5 & 0 & 1/5 & 1/5 & 1/5\\
1/5 & 1/5 & 0 & 1/5 & 2/5\\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

what will be the expected number of steps for being absorbed **given that we start in node 1 (first line) and the last state before absorption is node 2 (second line)** ?

So what I tried so far... I know the very known technique of using the fundamental matrix $N$ and then computing $N = (I-Q)^{-1}$ where $Q$ is the recurrent probabilities matrix (from the canonical form of $P$) and the expected number of steps would be the first entry of the vector $(I-Q)^{-1}1$, where $1$ is the five dimensional vector with all entries equal to $1$, in the case where we dont know the information about where we are absorbed.

Then, as we know that we are absorbed from node two, I tried to replace all the probabilties of the last columns by $0$ (execept for line $2$ and for the aborption node that I kept $2/5$ and $1$, respectively), then I am not pretty sure of how re-normalizing all the others...

Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: You want to compute $\mathbb{E}[\tau | \xi_{\tau-1} = 2]$, where $\xi_t$ is the state of the MC at time $t$ and $\tau$ the entrance time to state $5$?

Comment: If you have 5 states a line is missing in $P$!

Comment: @DieterKadelka Matrix updated ! And yes, it is exactly this that I need !

Comment: If $\mu(i,j)$ denotes the expected amount of time needed to reach state $j$ starting out at state $i$, then you have the relation $\mu(i,j) = 1 + \sum_{k \neq j} P_{ik} \mu(k,j)$. This should give the expected amount of time before being absorbed. I don't quite see yet how to take into account the given information about the state right before absorption.

Comment: Here's a proposal, though I'd like someone to fact-check it before I turn it into an answer. Let me write $j_a$ for the absorption state, $j_{i}$ for the initial state, and $j_{f}$ for the last state before absorption. Let $P'$ be the sub-Markov chain consisting of all states except $j_a$. In $P'$, compute $\mu(j_i,j_f)$ using the formula I gave above. Then the answer you're looking for should be $P_{j_f,j_a}^{-1} \cdot \mu(j_i,j_f)$.

Comment: $P^{-1}_{j_{f},j_{a}}$ is the $(j_{f},j_{a})$ element of the inverse matrix of $P$ or do you mean $\frac{1}{P_{j_{f},j_{a}}}$ ?

Comment: i meant the latter. Actually my comment is slightly inaccurate and I'm writing an answer for the corrected version but I'm struggling with the LaTeX errors... :p

Answer (score 1):

Let $S := \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be the state space of this homogeneous Markov chain (MC) and $\xi_n$ be the random state at time $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Let $\mathbb{P}_s$ be the joint distribution of $\xi_0,\xi_1,\ldots$ if the MC start in $s \in S$,  $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}_s)$ be the underlying probability space and $\tau$ be the entrance time in $s_a = 5$. Let $A := \{\xi_{\tau-1} = 2\}$ be the event that immediately before stopping the state is $2$ (with $\xi_{-1} := 5$). Of interest are $$\mathbb{E}_s[\tau ~|~ A] = \frac{g(s)}{f(s)}$$
with $f_s = \mathbb{P}_s(A)$ and $g(s) = \mathbb{E}_s Y$ with $Y = \tau \cdot 1_A$ ($1_A$ the indicator function of $A$) for $s \not= s_a$.

Let $P = (p_{si})_{s,i \in S}$ be the transition matrix of the MC. By the Markov property (here we don't need the strong Markov property) we get
$$\mathbb{P}_s(A) = 2/5 \cdot \delta_{s2} + \sum_{i=1}^5 p_{si} \cdot \mathbb{P}_i(A)$$
resp. $f = Pf + (0,2/5,0,0,0)'$. Since $f(5) = 0$ we can omit the state $s = 5$ and with $\tilde P := (p_{si})_{s,i \not= 5}$ we have to solve the equation
$$(\mathbb{1} - \tilde P) \tilde f = (0, 2/5, 0, 0)'$$. We get
$$\tilde f = (0.1897, 0.5, 0.1379, 0.1724)'$$

Similarly for $g$ we get
$$\mathbb{E}_s Y = \sum_{i \in S} p_{si} \mathbb{E}_i [Y ~|~ \xi_1 = i, \xi_0 = s]$$
with $\mathbb{E}_i [Y ~|~ xi_1 = i, \xi_0 = s] = 1$, if $s = 2, i = 5$, $ = 0$, if $s \not=2, i = 5$ or $s = 5$ and $= g_i+1$, else. Thus
$$g_s = (\tilde P (g+1))_s + 2/5 \cdot \delta_{s2}$$
resp. with $x = (g_1,\ldots,g_4)'$
$$x = \tilde P (x+1) + (0,2/5,0,0)' = \tilde P x + \tilde P (1,1,1,1)' + (0,2/5,0,0)'$$
with the solution $x = (2.9612, 2.6250, 3.0172, 2.1466)'$. In particular we get the solution $x(1)/f(1) = 15.6136$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly correcting my comments, and turning it into an answer. Let $P$ be the Markov chain you're interested in. Write $j_i$ for the initial state, $j_f$ for the last state before absorption, and $j_a$ for the absorption state. Write $P'$ for the sub-Markov chain consisting of all states except $j_a$. If $i$ and $j$ are states in a Markov chain, write $\mu(i,j)$ for the expected amount of steps needed to reach $j$ given that you start at $i$.

To find the expected amount of time to reach absorption given that you're in state $j_f$ right before that, what you'll want to do is make a summation over the amount of times that you've passed through $j_f$ before landing in $j_a$. With probability $P_{j_f,j_a}$, you'll need to pass through $j_f$ only once. With probability $(1 - P_{j_f,j_a}) P_{j_f,j_a}$, you'll need to pass through $j_f$ twice. And so on. Given that you pass through $j_f$ precisely $n+1$ times, the expected amount of time that you'll need to reach $j_a$ is
$$\mu(j_i,j_f) + n \cdot\mu(j_f,j_f) + 1,$$
where $\mu$ is computed in $P'$ (not in $P$; this is because we assume that on our path from $j_f$ back to itself, we don't get absorbed along the way). Now it's a matter of appropriate summation. Modulo errors I think the answer will be
$$E(T) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty P_{j_f,j_a} (1 - P_{j_f,j_a})^{n} \big(\mu(j_i,j_f) + n \cdot \mu(j_f,j_f) + 1\big)$$
which can be simplified to
$$E(T) = \mu(j_i,j_f) + 1 + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n P_{j_f,j_a} (1-P_{j_f,j_a})^{n} \mu(j_f,j_f),$$
and yet further to
$$E(T) = \mu(j_i,j_f) + \frac{1-P_{j_f,j_a} }{P_{j_f,j_a}}\mu(j_f,j_f) + 1.$$

Here's an approach for finding $\mu$. In a general Markov chain $Q$, the expected amount of time needed to pass from state $i$ to state $j$ satisfies the recurrence relation
$$\mu(i,j) = 1 + \sum_{k \neq j} Q_{i,k} \mu(k,j),$$
where the sum is taken over all states $k$ not equal to $j$. This formula should be enough to find $\mu(j_i,j_f)$ and $\mu(j_f,j_f)$ in $P'$ numerically.

Comment: Do we need to add $+1$ in the final answer, no ? This is, should the final answer be $\mathbb{E}(T) + 1$, for accounting to the final step from $j_{f}$ to $j_{a}$ ?

Comment: Oh! Yes, you are right.

Comment: In fact... Im asking myself, maybe we should add $+1$ in the  very first equation, and no in the final answer ?

Comment: Yes, there should be a $+1$ in every equation. I'll add it in. :)

Comment: Im not sure, but I think that the given $\mu$ equation is specific for a Markov Chain having an absorption node. In the new Markov Chain $P'$, we dont have an absorption node.

Comment: I dont know what is the basis case for this recurrence. Generally, when we have an absorption Markov Chain, the basis case is $\mu(j) = 0$ for every absorption state $j$.

Comment: @Carlgauss77 There is no basis case. Perhaps 'recurrence' was a bad word. But the equations for $\mu(i,j)$ always hold. The idea is that you just condition on the first transition out of the initial state $i$.

Comment: Ok, I found $\mu(k,j_{f}),$ for all $k$ solving a linear system of equations. One remaining doubt: When considering the sub Markov Chain $P'$, as the aborption state $j_{a}$ does not exist in this Markov chain, the probabilities will change, no ? This is, the matrix entries of $P'$ must change for the lines summing to $1$. Do you know how to modify the entries ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I think you'll need to normalise the entries (so just multiply them by the appropriate fixed factor so as to make the sum $1$ again).